# How to use two bottom sheets one after the other in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, bottom-sheet

My problem is that when I want to trigger my second bottom sheet which they are a Persistent bottom sheet it shows an error which is something related to the set state and the widget tree.

This is the error that I faced with it:
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 9238): The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 9238): This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered
I/flutter ( 9238): defunct).
I/flutter ( 9238): Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if
I/flutter ( 9238): the State is still active.
I/flutter ( 9238):
I/flutter ( 9238): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 9238): #0      State.context. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:951:9)
I/flutter ( 9238): #1      State.context (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:957:6)
I/flutter ( 9238): #2      _FleetPickerState._showSubFleets.... (package:mr_bar_driver/core/common/widgets/fleet_picker.dart:256:41)
I/flutter ( 9238): #3      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1203:30)
I/flutter ( 9238): #4      _FleetPickerState._showSubFleets... (package:mr_bar_driver/core/common/widgets/fleet_picker.dart:254:42)
I/flutter ( 9238): #5      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1183:21)
I/flutter ( 9238): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:275:24)
I/flutter ( 9238): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:652:11)
I/flutter ( 9238): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:309:5)
I/flutter ( 9238): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:279:7)
I/flutter ( 9238): #10     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:167:27)
I/flutter ( 9238): #11     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:492:20)
I/flutter ( 9238): #12     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:468:22)
I/flutter ( 9238): #13     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:439:11)
I/flutter ( 9238): #14     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:413:7)
I/flutter ( 9238): #15     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:376:5)
I/flutter ( 9238): #16     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:323:7)
I/flutter ( 9238): #17     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:292:9)
I/flutter ( 9238): #18     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:328:13)
I/flutter ( 9238): #19     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:410:7)
I/flutter ( 9238): #20     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:262:31)
I/flutter ( 9238):
I/flutter ( 9238): Handler: "onTap"
I/flutter ( 9238): Recognizer:
I/flutter ( 9238):   TapGestureRecognizer#033ae

And This is my code:

```
class FleetPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const FleetPicker({
    required this.fleets,
    super.key,
    this.flag = false,
  });

  final List<Fleet> fleets;
  final bool flag;

  @override
  State<FleetPicker> createState() => _FleetPickerState();
}

class _FleetPickerState extends State<FleetPicker> {
  String fleetName = '';
  String subFleetName = '';

  List<Fleet> fleets = [];
  List<Fleet> searchSubFleets = [];
  List<Fleet> subFleets = [];

  void _showSubFleets() {
    Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>(
      (context) => StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setStater) {
          return Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(Dimens.p32),
                topRight: Radius.circular(Dimens.p32),
              ),
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                colors: [
                  Colors.orange.shade900,
                  Colors.orange.shade800,
                  Colors.orange.shade400,
                ],
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Directionality(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: Dimens.p24,
                      vertical: Dimens.p24,
                    ),
                    width: context.width * .97,
                    height: context.height * .06,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      cursorColor: Colors.orange,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        if (mounted) {
                          setStater(() {
                            subFleets = Provider.of<FleetsProvider>(
                                  context,
                                  listen: false,
                                ).fleets ??
                                [];
                            searchSubFleets = subFleets
                                .where(
                                  (fleet) => fleet.title.contains(value),
                                )
                                .toList();
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        hintText: Strings.home14,
                        hintStyle: regularTextStyle(
                          color: Colours.white,
                          fontSize: Dimens.p14,
                        ),
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colours.white,
                        ),
                        fillColor: Colours.primary,
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimens.p24),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimens.p24),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimens.p24),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    height: context.height * .75,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: Dimens.p32,
                      left: Dimens.p12,
                    ),
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(Dimens.p64),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(Dimens.p64),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: subFleets.isNotEmpty
                          ? ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: searchSubFleets.isEmpty
                                  ? subFleets.length
                                  : searchSubFleets.length,
                              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                final fleet = searchSubFleets.isNotEmpty
                                    ? searchSubFleets[index]
                                    : subFleets[index];
                                return Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    Positioned(
                                      right: Dimens.p8,
                                      top: Dimens.p16,
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: Dimens.p54,
                                        height: Dimens.p54,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colors.orange.shade300,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                            Dimens.p27,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                            '${index + 1}',
                                            style: regularTextStyle(
                                              color: Colours.black,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    ClipShadow(
                                      clipper: CardClipper(),
                                      shadows: const [
                                        BoxShadow(
                                          blurRadius: 18,
                                          blurStyle: BlurStyle.inner,
                                          color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: context.width * .8,
                                        height: context.height * .08,
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: Dimens.p12,
                                          vertical: Dimens.p8,
                                        ),
                                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Colours.white,
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                            topRight:
                                                Radius.circular(Dimens.p32),
                                            bottomRight:
                                                Radius.circular(Dimens.p32),
                                            topLeft:
                                                Radius.circular(Dimens.p12),
                                            bottomLeft:
                                                Radius.circular(Dimens.p12),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: ListTile(
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(
                                                Dimens.p12,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            title: Directionality(
                                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                              child: Text(fleet.title),
                                            ),
                                            visualDensity: VisualDensity
                                                .adaptivePlatformDensity,
                                            contentPadding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              vertical: Dimens.p8,
                                              horizontal: Dimens.p16,
                                            ),
                                            onFocusChange: (_) {
                                              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                                            },
                                            onTap: () {
                                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                              setState(() {
                                                subFleetName = fleet.title;
                                              });

                                              setStater(() {
                                                searchSubFleets = [];
                                              });

                                              if (widget.flag) {
                                                Provider.of<FleetsIdProvider>(
                                                  context,
                                                  listen: false,
                                                ).initProfileSubFleetId(
                                                  fleet.id,
                                                );
                                              } else {
                                                Provider.of<FleetsIdProvider>(
                                                  context,
                                                  listen: false,
                                                ).initHomeSubFleetId(
                                                  fleet.id,
                                                );
                                              }
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                            )
                          : TimerLoadingView(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setStater(() {
                                  subFleets = Provider.of<FleetsProvider>(
                                        context,
                                        listen: false,
                                      ).fleets ??
                                      [];
                                });
                              },
                              text: Strings.home15,
                            ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet<void>(
          (context) => StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (context, setStater) {
              return Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(Dimens.p32),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(Dimens.p32),
                  ),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Colors.orange.shade900,
                      Colors.orange.shade800,
                      Colors.orange.shade400,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Directionality(
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: Dimens.p24,
                          vertical: Dimens.p24,
                        ),
                        width: context.width * .97,
                        height: context.height * .06,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          cursorColor: Colors.orange,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setStater(() {
                              fleets = widget.fleets
                                  .where(
                                    (fleet) => fleet.title.contains(value),
                                  )
                                  .toList();
                            });
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            filled: true,
                            hintText: Strings.home14,
                            hintStyle: regularTextStyle(
                              color: Colours.white,
                              fontSize: Dimens.p14,
                            ),
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                              color: Colours.white,
                            ),
                            fillColor: Colours.primary,
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimens.p24),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimens.p24),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimens.p24),
                              borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        height: context.height * .75,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: Dimens.p32,
                          left: Dimens.p12,
                        ),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(Dimens.p64),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(Dimens.p64),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: fleets.isEmpty
                                ? widget.fleets.length
                                : fleets.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              final fleet = fleets.isNotEmpty
                                  ? fleets[index]
                                  : widget.fleets[index];
                              return Stack(
                                children: [
                                  Positioned(
                                    right: Dimens.p8,
                                    top: Dimens.p16,
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: Dimens.p54,
                                      height: Dimens.p54,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.orange.shade300,
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(Dimens.p27),
                                      ),
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          '${index + 1}',
                                          style: regularTextStyle(
                                            color: Colours.black,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  ClipShadow(
                                    clipper: CardClipper(),
                                    shadows: const [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                        blurRadius: 18,
                                        blurStyle: BlurStyle.inner,
                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: context.width * .8,
                                      height: context.height * .08,
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                        horizontal: Dimens.p12,
                                        vertical: Dimens.p8,
                                      ),
                                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colours.white,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                          topRight: Radius.circular(Dimens.p32),
                                          bottomRight:
                                              Radius.circular(Dimens.p32),
                                          topLeft: Radius.circular(Dimens.p12),
                                          bottomLeft:
                                              Radius.circular(Dimens.p12),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: ListTile(
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                              Dimens.p12,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          title: Directionality(
                                            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                            child: Text(fleet.title),
                                          ),
                                          visualDensity: VisualDensity
                                              .adaptivePlatformDensity,
                                          contentPadding:
                                              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            vertical: Dimens.p8,
                                            horizontal: Dimens.p16,
                                          ),
                                          onFocusChange: (_) {
                                            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                                          },
                                          onTap: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              fleetName = fleet.title;
                                            });

                                            setStater(() {
                                              fleets = [];
                                            });

                                            if (widget.flag) {
                                              Provider.of<FleetsIdProvider>(
                                                context,
                                                listen: false,
                                              ).initProfileFleetId(
                                                fleet.id,
                                              );
                                            } else {
                                              Provider.of<FleetsIdProvider>(
                                                context,
                                                listen: false,
                                              ).initHomeFleetId(
                                                fleet.id,
                                              );
                                            }
                                            context.read<HomeBloc>().add(
                                                  HomeSubFleetFetcherEvent(
                                                    id: fleet.id,
                                                  ),
                                                );

                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                            _showSubFleets();
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        height: context.height * .06,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Dimens.p12),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimens.p8),
          border: Border.all(color: Colours.grey1),
          color: Colours.white,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            gapH12,
            const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colours.grey2),
            const Spacer(),
            Text(
              fleetName.isNotEmpty ? '($fleetName-$subFleetName)' : '',
              style: mediumTextStyle(
                color: Colours.primary,
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Text(
              Strings.home5,
              style: regularTextStyle(
                color: Colours.grey3,
                fontSize: Dimens.p12,
              ),
            ),
            gapW8,
            Assets.images.truck.svg(),
            gapW8,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Answer (score 0):

You can use `showModalBottomSheet` instead of `Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet`, for both sheets.

```
     await showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (context, setStater) {
               
            },
          ),
      );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've done as you said, but I'm still getting that error.